# How do you split user input?

Tags: mips

So say I had the user input an IP address 182.39.175.223 how would I split this input to get 182, 39, 175, 223 into different registers?

Comment: It is always best to include the code you have tried and its output.  Otherwise it may appear to some that you are looking to have someone else write your code for you.  And be a little more explicit about the environment of the request in the question body rather than just the tag.